# Expectation of a powered complex circular gaussian process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, normal-distribution, signal-processing

Assuming a **complex circular** zero-mean gaussian random process (or vector) $\textbf{x}$ $\left(\textbf{x}\sim \mathcal{CN}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)\right)$. $\mathbb{E}\{\textbf{x}\}=0$.

The question is: $\mathbb{E}\{\textbf{x}^n\} = ~?$ $\left(n\in\mathbb{N}^{*+}\right)$

PS: Through some Matlab simulations, the result seems to be equal to $0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x=R\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\Theta}$ where $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent, $E(x^n)=E(R^n)E(\mathrm e^{n\mathrm i\Theta})$. Furthermore, $E(\mathrm e^{n\mathrm i\Theta})=0$ for every integer $n$ because $\Theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$, hence $E(x^n)=0$.

Comment: If I have well understood, your answer is valid for all kind of distributions with zero-mean, and even non-circular ones. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: Please define "non-circular".

Comment: When the variance of $\Re\{\textbf{x}\}$ is different from $\Im\{\textbf{x}\}$ one.

Comment: Then this fails, already for n=2.

Comment: How ? Can you please explain.

Comment: Try x=2u+iv for (u,v) i.i.d. standard normal, then E(x^2)=3.

Comment: In fact, if the process is not circularly-symmetric, then $\Theta$ is no more uniformly distributed, and $\mathbb{E}\{e^{ni\Theta}\}=0$ only if $n$ is odd.